# Parsing tokens issue during interpreter development

Tags: c++, parsing, token

I'm building a code interpreter in C++ and while I have the whole token logic working, I ran into an unexpected issue.

The user inputs a string into the console, the program parses said string into different objects type Token, the problem is that the way I do this is the following:

```
void splitLine(string aLine) {

    stringstream ss(aLine);
    string stringToken, outp;
    char delim = ' ';

    // Break input string aLine into tokens and store them in rTokenBag
    while (getline(ss, stringToken, delim)) { 

        // assing value of stringToken parsed to t, this labes invalid tokens
        Token t (readToken(stringToken)); 

        R_Tokens.push_back(t);
    }   
}
```

The issue here is that if the parse receives a string, say `Hello World!` it will split this into 2 tokens `Hello` and `World!`

The main goal is for the code to recognize double quotes as the start of a string Token and store it whole (from `"` to `"`) as a single Token.
So if I type in `x = "hello world"` it will store `x` as a token, then next run `=` as a token, and then `hello world` as a token and not split it

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, exactly? I'm guessing you want "World" instead of "World!"?

Comment: @Thebluefish I want it to recognize "Hello World!" as a single token and not split it by the whitespace delim

Comment: The title doesnt seem to match the example given, how does "Hello world!" relate to parsing doubles?

Comment: I think you should first split your lines with character ' " ' to extract the 'real strings', and then split the rest with character ' '.

Comment: Check if you find a quote, and then ignore all whitespace until you find another quote.

Comment: @Borgleader I guess I dropped the ball on that one, I meant it as doing two parses

Comment: You are explicitly setting your ````delim```` to space for the getline call. This will split your input on each space.

Comment: Is it just double quotes you want to recognise? Or do you also care about single quotes, backticks, parentheses, brackets and braces?

Comment: @Beta Just double quotes so the code doesn't split a token string into 2. Again the problem is that I need it to store "Hello World!" as a whole token and not split it at the whitespace, while splitting the rest of the line by whitespace since anything that doesn't have double quotes is a different type of token/variable

Comment: @John Could you please update your question to indicate that? This detail would be helpful for others coming to the question so they don't need to dig through the comments...

Comment: C++14 has it built-in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted

Answer (score 2):

You can use C++14 [quoted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted) manipulator.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <iostream>

void splitLine(std::string aLine) {

    std::istringstream iss(aLine);
    std::string stringToken;

    // Break input string aLine into tokens and store them in rTokenBag
    while(iss >> std::quoted(stringToken)) {
        std::cout << stringToken << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {

    splitLine("Heloo world \"single token\" new tokens");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You really don't want to tokenize a programming language by splitting at a delimiter.

A proper tokenizer will switch on the first character to decide what kind of token to read and then keep reading as long as it finds characters that fit that token type and then emit that token when it finds the first non-matching character (which will then be used as the starting point for the next token).

That could look something like this (let's say `it` is an `istreambuf_iterator` or some other iterator that iterates over the input character-by-character):

```
Token Tokenizer::next_token() {
    if (isalpha(*it)) {
        return read_identifier();
    } else if(isdigit(*it)) {
        return read_number();
    } else if(*it == '"') {
        return read_string();
    } /* ... */
}

Token Tokenizer::read_string() {
    // This should only be called when the current character is a "
    assert(*it == '"');
    it++;
    string contents;
    while(*it != '"') {
        contents.push_back(*it);
        it++;
    }
    return Token(TokenKind::StringToken, contents);
}
```

What this doesn't handle are escape sequences or the case where we reach the end of file without seeing a second `"`, but it should give you the basic idea.

Something like `std::quoted` might solve your immediate problem with string literals, but it won't help you if you want `x="hello world"` to be tokenized the same way as `x = "hello world"` (which you almost certainly do).

---

PS: You can also read the whole source into memory first and then let your tokens contain indices or pointers into the source rather than strings (so instead of the `contents` variable, you'd just save the start index before the loop and then return `Token(TokenKind::StringToken, start_index, current_index)`). Which one's better depends partly on what you do in the parser. If your parser directly produces results and you don't need to keep the tokens around after processing them, the first one is more memory-efficient because you never need to hold the whole source in memory. If you create an AST, the memory consumption will be about the same either way, but the second version will allow you to have one big string instead of many small ones.

Comment: The logic behind my program is: split the input string into Tokens and put them in the right stack. Then one by one pass them to the left stack by doing what you say, read first then decide if the next works or not.

This only works if I can split the input string into the tokens I need

Comment: @John What you do with your tokens after you generated them is another matter entirely and doesn't really affect how you generate them. I'm saying that your approach of splitting at a delimiter simply won't work for any language with even slightly non-trivial lexical rules (as seen in my `x="hello world"` example). So you'll need to generate tokens by processing the input character-by-character instead of trying to get one token at a time via `operator>>`'s built-in splitting. After that you can process the generated token stream token-by-token.

Comment: Then I better get to reading, because I don't have a single clue on how to do what you just said, and you're right it should allow for writing without the use of a whitespace delim. What would be a way to implement this? Use substr() on the input string and see if it equals a defined token? And if it does then delete the substr() and continue?

Comment: @John I've added a code example to my answer. Maybe that makes things clearer.

Comment: Hey just wanted to let you know I figured out a way to do it with getline(). But thanks for all your help anyway, I know my method is probably horrible in practice, but I'm a bit rushed and am doing this solo when it's supposed to be a 5 man effort. Again, thank you a bunch for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out, and I CAN use getline() to achieve my goals.

This new code runs and parses the way I need it to be:

```
    void splitLine(string aLine) {

    stringstream ss(aLine);
    string stringToken, outp;
    char delim = ' ';

    while (getline(ss, stringToken, delim)) { // Break line into tokens and store them in rTokenBag

        //new code starts here
        // if the current parse sub string starts with double quotes
        if (stringToken[0] == '"' ) { 

            string torzen;
            // parse me the rest of ss until you find another double quotes
            getline(ss, torzen, '"' ); 

           // Give back the space cut form the initial getline(), add the parsed sub string from the second getline(), and add a double quote at the end that was cut by the second getline()
            stringToken += ' ' + torzen + '"'; 

        }
        // And we can all continue with our lives 
        Token t (readToken(stringToken)); // assing value of stringToken parsed to t, this labes invalid tokens

        R_Tokens.push_back(t);

    }


}
```

Thanks to everyone who answered and commented, you were all of great help!